# Using a script to turn a video into a dataset of training images

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a video on my Videos folder that I'd like to turn into an image dataset for my CV model.  This is the script I'm using:

```
import cv2
import os

cam = cv2.VideoCapture('../Videos/training-videos/0.mp4')

try:
    if not os.path.exists('../Videos/training-videos/data0'):
        os.makedirs('../Videos/training-videos/data0')
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data0')

current_frame = 0

while (True):

    ret, frame = cam.read()

    if ret:
        name = './data/frame' + str(current_frame) + '.jpg'
        print('Creating...' + name)

        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

        current_frame += 1
    else:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And I'm getting the following output:

```
...
Creating..../data/frame19485.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19486.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19487.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19488.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19489.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19490.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19491.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19492.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19493.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19494.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19495.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19496.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19497.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19498.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19499.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19500.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19501.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19502.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19503.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19504.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19505.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19506.jpg
Creating..../data/frame19507.jpg
```

This is all fine and well.  It also creates the `../Videos/training-videos/data0` folder but there are no images inside.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: shouldn't name be `name =  '../Videos/training-videos/data0/frame' + str(current_frame) + '.jpg'`

Comment: But how would that affect the process?  The images aren't created at all.

Comment: Are you sure that you have writing permission? what is your relative path?

Comment: @SaeedMasoomi I'm not sure of that but the folders are created..

Comment: there are no images inside, because the directory specified by name is not the same as the `../Videos/training-videos/data0` aren't you saying there are no images inside that folder?

Comment: did you create the (sub)folders? OpenCV assumes the folders are already present. Do you have access rights to the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code it worked for me. Just replace your path in the path variable. If you want to use a relative path then you need to specify the whole path. Other than this you were creating a directory *data0* and you were trying to place your images in *data*.

```
import cv2
import os

path = 'C:/Users/hp/Pictures/Camera Roll'
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(path, 'video.mp4'))

try:
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, 'data0')):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, 'data0'))
except OSError:
    print('Error: Creating directory of data0')

current_frame = 0

while (True):

    ret, frame = cam.read()

    if ret:
        name = 'data0/frame' + str(current_frame) + '.jpg'
        name = os.path.join(path, name)
        print('Creating...' + name)

        cv2.imwrite(name, frame)

        current_frame += 1
    else:
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I don't think that we have to provide whole path for `imwrite` function, Did you see any document about that?

Comment: You would have to if you want to use an absolute path. If you want to use a relative path then the path of the folder you are creating would also have to be relative.